# Solar cell short circuit current

Tags: semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

In order to obtain a solution to the short circuit current in a solar cell a boundary condition

n=p=0 at the junction

is imposed. Why only for short circuit current?

Comment: What are $n$ and $p$?

Comment: What condition is the diode in while under 'short circuit' conditions? What impact does that have on carrier concentrations in different regions of the cell?

Comment: $n(x)$ and $p(x)$ are the electron and hole concentrations at position $x$. Under short circuit the $n(x)$ and $p(x)$ ends are connected by a wire that is short circuited.

Comment: To be more precise $n$ and $p$ are the excess concentrations over the equilibrium (no light) value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because in the short circuit case no voltage other than built-in voltage exsist at the junction.